# Using jasmine the correct way or creating a testAll-spec

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I have to say I'm kinda stuck with using jasmine(-node) in (most probably) a slightly wrong way. Currently I have jasmine tests so, that they need to be run in a correct order. I would at the moment need to have a file that can collect and initiate the different jasmine-files in the correct order.

Now I appreciate advice, which show me other ways of making the testing work well and not necessarily just fix this immediate problem, my testing skills are fairly limited,  mostly because as a long time solo-coder I haven't had that much use for them.

So the actual problem is that I have test-specs:

1. mapGenerator-spec.js // Initializes / generates a clean map.
2. orders-spec.js // Simulates orders given by players (turn based)
3. map-spec.js // tests the part which is used front-end and backend, creating map from components
4. moveOrders-spec.js // Generates a part of the turn by resolving orders -> moving units.

So simply the logic in a game is that first generates a map, order generate orders given by players

These need to be executed in the precise order, because they create database-entries that are dependant on the previous test. I would like to keep the tests as product-ready / real as possible and not try to skip the database-inserts / fetches. There is a separate test-database, where the tests are generated.

So can you advice me, what you think is the correct way to do this (if this is not a good way) and / or advice me, if needed, how can I sum up these tests to one collection test "testAll-spec.js", which would run the tests synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something to happen before you run a test, then you should use beforeEach().

You can also nest jasmine tests, and run a beforeEach() within each test, as below:

```
describe('testInitialiser', () => {
    var firstVariable;
    beforeEach(() => {
        firstVariable = 1;
    });
    it('should set firstVariable to 1', () => {
        expect(firstVariable).toBe(1); 
    });
    // this is a nested test - these tests will run after the above beforeEach.
    describe('nested test ', () => {
        // all tests within this describe will have access to firstVariable.
        var secondVariable;
        beforeEach(() => {
            secondVariable = firstVariable + 1;
        });
        it('should set secondVariable to firstVariable + 1 ', () => {
            expect(secondVariable).toBe(2); 
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well the problem is that I have the 4 (or more) separate test-specs. I can run them individually in correct order and get the tests to pass. They all use database and are not mocked in any way really. I need to basically combine them, so that I can easily run the tests in the correct order or have a way to make them not be independent of each other.  
  
The latter is kinda hard since I would need to initiate the database  and previous tests in each of the tests separately.